# In a question should I ask "Can I change" or "can I changed"?

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

Which of these questions is correct

> Can I change the call to action in the version CN?

or

> Can I changed the call to action in the version CN?

Comment: Can I change the call to action in the CN version?

Comment: I  am almost sure that in your mother tongue "can" is followed by an infinitive and not by a past form or a past participle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of auxiliary verb 'can' requires an infinitive.  The affirmative sentence is

> I can **change** the call to action in the version CN.

To form a question, you split the verb construct by the subject:

> Can ***I*** change ...

without any additional transformation of the words.  If you want to form the past tense of the same affirmative sentence, you say

> I **could** change the call to action in the version CN.

and to form a question you again move the auxiliary verb to the beginning of the sentence without changing anything else

> **Could** I change the call ...

Answer (score 3):

The modal verbs *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would* require the a following verb cast in the infinitive or 'plain' form, so *changed* is not permissible here. You must say

> Can I change ... ?

This is true whether the clause is a statement or a question:

> Yes, you can change ...

It's not clear what leads to ask about *change* in the past/past participle form. Two things you might be trying to express:

- If you want to cast this in the past tense, you must use the past form  *could*

  > I asked whether I *could* change ...

  Note that the past form *could* should be used only in contexts where it is clear that a past-tense meaning is intended. *Could* is most often used to signify "modal remoteness" rather than past tense: that is, it signals a tentative or hypothetical or counterfactual sense. Without an explicit context you should use another verb: *be able* if you are using *can* to talk about ability, *be allowed* or *be permitted* if you are using *can* to talk about permission:

  > Were you able to change ... ?
  >   Were you permitted to change ... ?
- *Can* itself cannot be cast in the passive voice, but its complement may be. In this case you must use the auxiliary *be*, and it is that which is cast in the obligatory infinitive form:

  > Can the call ***be*** changed ... ?
  >   The call can ***be*** changed ...